# Why does Set not allow Object.values().length to be utilized, when it is defined as an object that stores values?

Tags: javascript, object, set

let's say

```
let visited = new Set();

//(pretend we ran visited.add() a few times to populate it...)

console.log(Object.values(visited).length);
```

Why would this always return 0, regardless of how many items are stored in the Set object? Sure, visited.size and Array.from(visited).length would return the correct number, but if MDN defines .size as the length of the values in the object how is visited.size !== Object.values(visited).length?!?

Comment: What do you think `Object.values` means?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what `Object.values` does. Unlike arrays, sets do not expose their values in object properties.

Comment: You assume, that `Set` saves elements as some properties directly on itself. This is not the case. a) `Set` is a native implementation, and doesn't need to care about regular javascript objects at all. b) even otherwise, imagine this: `class Set { values = {}; add(x) { this.values[Symbol()] = x; } }` - although all elements are properties of some object, they are not properties of the set (`Object.values(someSet).length` would always be `1`).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`Set#size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size), which returns the count of items in the set.

Your approach with

```
Object.values(visited).length
```

returns the own enumerable values of an object, which is here not given, so length is always zero.